# How to add all i values that are printed?

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I add all int `i` values that are printed?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { System.out.println(i); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, not at all.
I hope to help you with the following code:

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        sum=sum+i;
    } 
System.out.println("Sum ="+sum);
```